# Passing data from content script to options page

Tags: google-chrome

Is there any simple way of passing data (a simple string) from a content script in a Google Chrome extension to the options page of the same extension?

My background page is not persistent and I would like to keep it that way.

I tried both `window.postMessage` and `chrome.extension.sendMessage`, but somehow what works with the background page does not work with the options page. Am I overlooking something obvious?

Comment: Well, `chrome.extension.sendMessage` _should_ work, but unoptimally, you can try [`chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage`](https://developer.chrome.com/dev/extensions/runtime.html#method-getBackgroundPage).

Comment: chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage() sometimes only seems to work, when the background page is active.

Comment: oh, your options page, misread that. can't you use [chrome.storage](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage.html)?

Comment: Yes, using `chrome.storage` would be possible, but I am reading data that changes over time with the versions of the extension, so just pushing it into `chrome.storage` for the sake of exchanging with the Options page does not seem like a clean solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is to message from the Content Script to the background page, keep the message there and then message from the Options dialog to the background page and retrieve it. Both using `chrome.extension.sendMessage`.